# Drawing and saving an image as JPEG in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am creating an app which allows user to draw a digit(using mouse) in Canvas. When they click on submit, the image should be saved as a JPEG and Clear should Erase the digit drawn in canvas. I am new to HTML5 Canvas. I saw some tutorials which created a canvas, but I am unable to save and clear canvas. Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 210px;">
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" id="clear" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
</div></div>
</div>
```

Javascript within Script tag:

```
var clear = document.getElementById('clear');
clear.addEventListener('click', clearCanvas);
var clearCanvas = function(e) {
   ctx.fillStyle = "white";
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 400);
   ctx.clearRect(20, 20, 100, 50);
}
```

Comment: There's a thorough tutorial here: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/

Comment: @RichardInglis has linked to a nice sketching app in canvas. Here's a separate link on how to save the completed canvas sketch to your user's local drive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299050/how-to-use-filesaver-js-with-canvas/28305948#28305948.

Comment: @RichardInglis: I tried that tutorial, I see a border for the canvas in my html page, but I am unable to draw a digit in it. Updated my question with the HTML I tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial you're using fails to mention a few key things:

- The `canvasInAPerfectWorld`line isn't used: you can delete it.
- You need jQuery: just add `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script/>` in your `<head>` section.
- You should wrap your javascript in the jQuery boilerplate, to ensure it gets executed after the rest to the document has loaded: `$( document ).ready(function() { <your javascript here> });`
- The `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` variables are never set: add this line before the variables are used:`var canvasWidth = 600; var cavasHeight = 400;`
- The variables mouseX and mouseY are never used: you can delete them (but take a look at the `onClick()` function two lines later to see what they would have been used for).

The finished result should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 Create HTML5 Canvas JavaScript Drawing App Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<style>canvas { border: 1px solid #ccc; }</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
var canvasWidth = 600; var cavasHeight = 400;

var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', cavasHeight);
canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
    canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

$('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
      paint = true;
      addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
      redraw();
    });

$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
      if(paint){
        addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
        redraw();
      }
    });

$('#canvas').mouseup(function(e){
      paint = false;
    });

$('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
      paint = false;
    });

$('#clear').click(function(){
  clickX.length = 0;
  clickY.length = 0;
  clickDrag.length = 0;
  redraw();
});

var clickX = new Array();
var clickY = new Array();
var clickDrag = new Array();
var paint;

function addClick(x, y, dragging)
{
  clickX.push(x);
  clickY.push(y);
  clickDrag.push(dragging);
}

function redraw(){
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

      context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
      context.lineJoin = "round";
      context.lineWidth = 5;

      for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) {        
        context.beginPath();
        if(clickDrag[i] && i){
          context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
         }else{
           context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
         }
         context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
         context.closePath();
         context.stroke();
      }
    }
    });
   </script>
   </head>
     <body>
       <div id="canvasDiv"></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

---

As for **saving** your canvas as a JPEG, that's more complicated. As [markE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411591/marke) has pointed out, there's a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299050/how-to-use-filesaver-js-with-canvas/28305948#28305948) which shows one way to do it.

---

**EDIT**: Adding a 'Clear' button:

Your 'drawing' is really just a series of pen movements stored in the clickX, clickY and clickDrag arrays. Each time `redraw()` is called, the drawing gets recreated from the arrays. So just drawing a white rectangle will only clear the screen until the next `redraw()`. Instead, you can clear the arrays by adding this to your javascript:

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
  clickX.length = 0;
  clickY.length = 0;
  clickDrag.length = 0;
  redraw();
});
```

*(BTW by deleting the details of your original question, you make it hard for the next person to understand the context of the answers. You should either (a) add to your original question, or (b) ask a new question. Also you can upvote and/or accept any answers you find helpful. Thanks)*

Comment: Thank you so much @Richard. It worked. I am able to draw digits number. I also want to implement a Clear and Save functionality for this. I have updated by code above with the Clear. But its not working. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: The tutorial link is broken now...

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a duplicated question. See here

[Can I get image from canvas element and use it in img src tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257781/can-i-get-image-from-canvas-element-and-use-it-in-img-src-tag)

```
var image = new Image();
image.id = "pic"
image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
document.getElementById('image_for_crop').appendChild(image);
```

Comment: I also saw this question, but its different. I am trying to draw an image, whereas in that question they are attaching an existing image to canvas.